# How can I connect to mysql database on a remote host using c# winform app on my local pc?

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I have already implement a control panel for MySQL database. That works perfect with local database which is installed on my PC. But when i try to connecting with mysql database on my web host i get this message:

> cannot connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

Here is my connection string:

```
var csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Server =  "database.webhost.com",
    Port=     "3306"
    UserID =  "root",
    Password ="1234567",
    Database ="sampleDB",
    SslMode=  "None",

};
```

I was reading something about SSH secure connections to web hosts, but i can't find any examples.

Comment: You need to read the documentation provided by `webhost.com` on how to connect to MySQL remotely. You may have to enable access to the particular IP addresses your program will be connecting from.

Comment: Thank you it was helpful. I need a SSH tunnel to connect remotely to my web  database server.